# Leaflet multiple provider tiles with lapply

Tags: r, leaflet, lapply

I would like to add **OpenStreetMap**, **OpenTopoMap** and **Stamen.TonerLines** in a list to a leaflet map.

I get those names with

```
library("leaflet"); library("leafem")
names(providers)[c(1,10,40)]
[1] "OpenStreetMap"     "OpenTopoMap"       "Stamen.TonerLines"
```

My map is this

```
n = leaflet() %>% 
addTiles(group = "Base") %>% 
setView( lng = 1, lat = 40, zoom = 5 ) 
n
```

[image]

My `lapply`  code is this

```
lapply(
  c(1,10,40),  
  function(i) addProviderTiles(map=n, names(providers)[i], layerId = i, group =names(providers)[i]) 
)

lapply(
  c(1,10,40), 
  function(i) addLayersControl(map=n, baseGroups = names(providers)[i]) 
)
```

Now I have only last tile!

[image]

How could I add those tiles using lapply?

Comment: I've never used this mapping package, but it could be due to `lapply` returning the output in list form. you may have better luck with `for( i in c(1,10,40) ){ ... }` Since your functions do not appear to be vectorized there should be no difference in performance.

Comment: In some readings, I found that looping with ``` for() ``` could be slower than ``` lapply ``` in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
n = leaflet() %>% 
addTiles(group = "Base") %>% 
setView( lng = 1, lat = 40, zoom = 5 )

n %>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = 'OpenStreetMap') %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenTopoMap, group='OpenTopoMap') %>% 
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c('OpenStreetMap', 'OpenTopoMap'))
```

To wrap into a function calling index

```
layered_map <- function(..., provider=NULL, base_map_name="Base") {
  select_providers <- provider[c(...)]
  iter <- function(providers, layerid) {
    if (length(providers)==0) {
      leaflet() %>% addTiles(group = base_map_name) %>% setView(lng = 1, lat = 40, zoom = 5 )
      } else {
        iter(providers[-length(providers)], layerid-1) %>% 
          addProviderTiles(providers[[length(providers)]], 
                           layerId = layerid, 
                           group = providers[[length(providers)]])
      }
  }

  controlnames <- if (length(select_providers)==0) base_map_name else names(select_providers)
  iter(select_providers, length(select_providers)) %>% addLayersControl(baseGroups = controlnames)
}
```

To call the function:

```
library("leaflet")
library("leafem")
layered_map(1, 10, 40, provider=providers)
```

[image: map with multiple layers and controls]

It is quite generic. So, if you want to generate a base map without additional layers. You could simply do

```
layered_map()
```

or

```
layered_map(base_map_name="My base map")
```

which will give you
[image: base map]

Comment: With recursive calls!!! It is amazing!!
Thank you, @englealuze